# Backbone Router does not trigger for direct URLs - using Meteor

Tags: backbone.js, meteor

I am using the same basic Router code from the ToDo's example, but I am running into some issues. When I Router.navigateToItem(itemID) everything works. However, if I enter in a direct url (/inventory/itemId), then the Session variable is never set and thus the direct URL doesnt work. I can figure out how to get the Router to trigger via direct URL. Thank help is much appreciated. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
var WebRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "": "main",
      "inventory/:itemId": "itemDetail"
    },
    main: function () {
      Session.set("inventoryItem", null);
    },
    itemDetail: function(itemId) {
      Session.set("inventoryItem", Items.find({_id:itemId}).fetch()[0]);
    },
    navigateToItem: function(itemId) {
      this.navigate("inventory/"+itemId, {trigger: true});
    }
  });

  Router = new WebRouter;

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
  });
```

Edit 1:

I notices that if I do not pushState:

```
Backbone.history.start();
```

Then everything seems to work. However, then I have this stupid hash symbol in my url and I dont know where it came from: /#inventory/WsL7YZxiWk3Cv3CgT

Getting closer... I'm also unsure what is lost without pushState...

Edit 2:

Another failed attempt:

```
  window.onload= function(){
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    Router.navigate(url.substring(1,url.length), {trigger: true});
    console.log(url.substring(1,url.length));
  };
```

I really thought this one was going to work, but it doesnt...

Comment: This does not solve your current problem, but have you tried the [Meteor Router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router)? It's super easy to use (IMO) and will work down to IE8.

Comment: im pretty new to web development. This doesnt look too easy to me -- I dont know what page.js is, then I start looking through that and just find more and more that I dont understand... :/

Comment: Yeah you'll need meteorite to use it, but once you've got meteorite installed it's just a matter of writing `mrt add router` to add the router to your project. It'll add page.js in the process (and you don't really need to know anything about page.js, it just depends on it).

Comment: just started with meteorite -- good call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It happened to be a more subtle issue that hard to explain and I'm not entirely sure I fully understand it:

I would set a session variable to an object from the database, rather than setting the session variable to the database object id and reactively linking that database object to the template...

Regardless, I changed these lines:

```
  Template.inventory.inventoryItem = function () {
    return Session.get("inventoryItem");
  }  

  Session.set("inventoryItem", Items.find({_id:Session.get("inventoryItem")}).fetch()[0];);
```

Changed to:

```
  Template.inventory.inventoryItem = function () {
    return Items.find({_id:Session.get("inventoryItem")}).fetch()[0];
  } 

  Session.set("inventoryItem", itemId);
```

And now everything magically works...

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure your server to redirect all URLs to serve up the content that gets served when requesting the root. Backbone only handles the URL after the page has been loaded, if you don't have your server configured to handle the URLs then Backbone will never get loaded because the HTML never gets sent.